# How to copy down matrix that references a row in Excel?

Tags: excel, matrix

I am trying to calculate a few hundred rows of data, solving a system of linear equations using matrices. I am building my matrices based on the row data. I take the inverse of the resultant 3x3 and then multiply twice, once for x's and once for y's. I get 6 variables from this: `a,b,c,d,e` and `f`. How can I copy down the example so that is solves for all rows? I am providing the data and then the formulas I am using now. Right now, if I copy down it skips 3 rows or if I copy down with 3 examples it skips 9 rows. I mean I guess I could go an try to insert extra rows into all 300 so I end up with 900 rows, but there has to be an easier way!

I can't figure out how to get my data to populate in here correctly so here is a link: http://codepad.org/qZwua3h9

Note: I split up the matrix rows so you could see them easier, they are not split up on my sheet.

Edit: If anyone can figure out how to paste the example data here I would welcome it so that this post may be of use to someone in the future. I am not sure how long codepad keeps their pastes.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and came to the conclusion that there is no reasonable amount of effort that will yield the desired results. Not only was the example case only ONE transformation, but the intended case was for 3 transformations - so three times the work. I came up with a Matlab solution in about 15 minutes. I understand that not everyone has access to Matlab though. So, if someone comes up with any reasonable working excel solution, I would welcome the knowledge and mark that answer as the accepted one. Regardless, here is the Matlab script:

```
  M = csvread('pointData.csv');

  T1result = zeros(215,6);
  T2result = zeros(215,6);
  T3result = zeros(215,6);

  for i=1:215,
      m = [M(i,1) M(i,2) 1; M(i,3) M(i,4) 1; M(i,5) M(i,6) 1];
      x = [M(i,7);M(i,9);M(i,11)];
      y = [M(i,8);M(i,10);M(i,12)];
      xresult = m\x;
      yresult = m\y;
      T1result(i,:) = [transpose(xresult),transpose(yresult)];

      m = [M(i,7) M(i,8) 1; M(i,9) M(i,10) 1; M(i,11) M(i,12) 1];
      x = [M(i,13);M(i,15);M(i,17)];
      y = [M(i,14);M(i,16);M(i,18)];
      xresult = m\x;
      yresult = m\y;
      T2result(i,:) = [transpose(xresult),transpose(yresult)];

      m = [M(i,13) M(i,14) 1; M(i,15) M(i,16) 1; M(i,17) M(i,18) 1];
      x = [M(i,19);M(i,21);M(i,23)];
      y = [M(i,20);M(i,22);M(i,24)];
      xresult = m\x;
      yresult = m\y;
      T3result(i,:) = [transpose(xresult),transpose(yresult)];
  end

  LeafId = csvread('extraColumnsForID.csv');
  Tresult = [LeafId, T1result, T2result, T3result];

  csvwrite('transforms.csv',Tresult);
```